# Which is faster, iteratively setting the values of a pandas df column by index or set value on multiple indexes?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Recently I have been iterating through a data frame column. I had to set the same value on the multiple indexes in that df's column. This arises the question - can we set multiple indexes without the for loop if yes is it faster?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
  "calories": [420, 380, 390],
  "duration": [50, 40, 45]
}

#load data into a DataFrame object:
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['demo'] = [None] * len(df)
df['demon'] = [None] * len(df)

%%time
for idx in df.index:
    df['demo'][idx] = 'b'
# CPU times: user 1.38 ms, sys: 3.22 ms, total: 4.59 ms
# Wall time: 7.52 ms

%%time
df['demo'][df.index] = 'a'
# CPU times: user 593 µs, sys: 30 µs, total: 623 µs
# Wall time: 612 µs
```

Iterating over indexes to set the same value is slower than setting them at once and is natively supported by pandas.